# Question about collections of custom GUI controls for Mathematica

Tags: programming, dynamic, gui-construction, undocumented

Background: I have only recently begun programming GUIs in Mathematica, so I have a continuous need for custom controls. I needed a scrollable list control and with the help of Google I found a beautiful one [in this MathGroup post](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Apr/msg00733.html) (One of Sjoerd, if I am correct.) The point being: there is a lot of excellent Mathematica code shattered all over. Most matured languages have libraries of custom controls. I am not aware of any existing for Mathematica.

**Question(s): What is the best *managed* collection of (open source) custom GUI controls for Mathematica that you know of? Where do you get your custom GUI controls? Should there be a collection of custom GUI controls for Mathematica?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

One of the excellent places to look is the [Wolfram Demonstration Project](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com). There are many cases with custom controls there. You can test out controls immediately and download the source code. Because I know that site pretty well I will keep the list here.

[Relief-Shaded Elevation Map](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ReliefShadedElevationMap/)

[image]

[3D Waves](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/3DWaves/)

[image]

[Potter's Wheel](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PottersWheel/)

[image]

[Motion Blur](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/MotionBlur/)

[image]

[Contours of Algebraic Surfaces](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ContoursOfAlgebraicSurfaces/)

[image]

[Polar Area Sweep](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/PolarAreaSweep/)

[image]

[Color Quantization...](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ColorQuantizationOfPhotographicImagesIIPaletteFromColorsOutO/)  [Tracing Contour...](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TracingContourLinesInPhotographicImages/)   [Creating Posters...](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CreatingPostersFromPhotographicImages/)

[image]

[Relationship between the Tone Curve and the Histogram of a Photographic Image](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/RelationshipBetweenTheToneCurveAndTheHistogramOfAPhotographi/)

[image]

Complex nested controls: [Two-Dimensional Block Cellular Automata with a 2×2 Neighborhood](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TwoDimensionalBlockCellularAutomataWithA22Neighborhood/)

[image]

Interesting type - the content is the control: [Block Builder](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/BlockBuilder/)

[image]

Constrained locators: [Sweet Heart](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/SweetHeart/)

[image]

Answer (score 17):

- Some you can find in the Documentation Center, like the angular slider in [Dynamic's](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Dynamic.html) documentation (under **[Applications](http://wolfram.com/xid/0mrdma-l1va85)**), or the `ValueThumbSlider` in the [Advanced Manipulate Functionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html) section (under **[Custom Control Appearances](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#651832353)**).
- Some you can find in developer packages like the angular slider in the `` "Experimental`" `` package:

  `` Needs@"Experimental`"; AngularSlider[] ``

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that these are not part of official *Mathematica* yet, so they can be changed with any new release without any notification.

- Some you can find in StackOverflow or on MathGroup, like Heike's [toggling `MouseOver` button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8791746/712498), Szabolcs's [zooming rectangle](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2008/Jan/msg00009.html) or my [SplitPane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7697640/712498) gui element or a gridded `TogglerBar`: [`TogglerGrid`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7563/89), or a [throbber](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7577/89).
- Some you have to write for your own. It's really not that hard once you get a grip on `Dynamic`, `DynamicModule` and `EventHandler`.
- I've written many controls, some specific some more general, I would be glad to share them, though I don't know of any specific place where the *Mathematica* community shares functions/libraries other than SE (and SO). Some of the dynamic controls that I've designed and used (since *Mathematica* 6 was introduced) I am going to list here (or somewhere) in the future. One particularly complex controller to manipulate 2D plots can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7144/89).

Comment: I think we (as a community) should start using Github or something equivalent. Sharing small snippets on SE is not a problem, but for larger packages it gets cumbersome.

Comment: @Ajasja I think many (or at least some) of us are already using GitHub, which has a number of features making it a good choice for this purpose. There was also a [meta discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/227/is-there-a-stackexchange-like-public-repository-for-mathematica-code) related to this.

Comment: Yes, the SplitPane, an example of an excellent control that needs a more prominent home where it can be maintained, i.e. continuously improved and made consistent with an entire family of similar, well documented, controls.

Comment: @Leonid, Ajasja, ndroock1 Since this site was created, the idea that there should be a more organized way to collaborate keeps coming up again and again.  Perhaps it's time to start a discussion on meta?

Comment: @Szabolcs: I second your motion.

Comment: @Szabolcs, Istvan Guys, I agree with you in general,  but I'll tell you straight away that my opinion is that we should wait for some more with this. If some of you ask this on meta, I will try to explain my reasoning. At the same time, I am not at all against the idea. I just don't think that we should make some decisions now. The collaboration process will grow organically in time, when many regulars here will get more time on their hands, because a wider part of our community will assist in answering questions. I think what we need for serious work now is free time, not infrastructure.

Comment: @IstvánZachar, Szabolcs For example, I have about 5 projects I am currenty working on, with various degrees of completeness, and many more in my plans. Some of them you know, because I posted the (often simplified) code here on SE, some not, but the point is that my work is very slow, in big part because I spend so much time here answering questions. I suspect that many regulars here have a similar situation. We are still very young as a community, and try hard to make it gain more momentum. Once it gets it fully and stable, we can start real work. This is just my opinion, of course.

Comment: @Leonid: Hmm... I might seem like a yes-man, but I have to agree with you too. Time is a really serious bottleneck and I've just realized that cleaning up all my gui-control code needs more than a lazily spent afternoon. Still, it would be a good thing to at least keep the idea of a repo on the surface in the community, as we might be able to attract those who like to dig code more than to ask or answer quesions.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin It is a wonderful helpful community. I have learned so much from you guys. All that beautiful code deserves a better, more prominent place, not in the least to honor your work.

Comment: @ndroock1 I agree with you. I just think that it can wait for a little more (like a month or two). There are some fundamental problems with making code sharing efficient for smaller code snippets. They are not unsolvable, but require careful considerations and design. I have some ideas on the matter and have already done some work on that, but, let me just say, that for now a combination of SE (this site) for smaller code snippets plus GitHub for larger projects should be IMO good enough for most people. I just have this feeling that we should first get more stable.

Comment: @Istvan GitHub would be a good place for now, I think. Create an account there, and you can use GitHub [gists](https://gist.github.com/) to post code. Gists are light-weight repositories, where you just create one or a few files, they are versioned, can be edited online, can be commented on. I have some of my smaller projects as gists, and find them pretty convenient.

Comment: @Leonid: Thanks for the link, I've created the account, and now am trying to understand how things work. Expect some Git-related questions on meta in the future :)

Comment: @IstvánZachar Ok, great! It is great that you also started this. We need some critical mass of people to start using the same place (IMO GitHub is a good choice).

Answer (score 10):

You can also look at the [`` GUIKit` ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/guide/GUIKitPackage.html) package which allows you to create complicated widgets and panels that mimic the look and feel of the OS. The [user guide/tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/Overview.html) is pretty decent and has several examples too that you can learn from and modify to your needs. In fact, a lot of the additional editing/explorer functionality like `GraphEdit` and `DatabaseExplorer` are designed using this. You can find some of these files in `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/`. Some examples from the documentation:

1. [Text import wizard:](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/TextImportWizard.html)

   Import text files into Mathematica like you can in MS Excel and set delimiters and other options.

   [image]
2. [`NIntegrate` explorer](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/NIntegrateExplorer.html)

   > The NIntegrate Explorer is a GUI that lets you do numerical quadrature using NIntegrate. It opens a tool that lets you enter an integrand, set a region, then modify and change the various option settings for NIntegrate. The result of the computation is shown, along with a graphical display of the function evaluations, as well as the input to NIntegrate that was used.

   [image]
3. [EquationTrekker](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/EquationTrekker/tutorial/EquationTrekker.html)

   > ... an interactive tool for investigating the solutions of differential equations as well as other types of equations that have solutions that can be viewed as paths or trajectories.

   [image]

   > [`EquationTrekker` allows] you to investigate the solutions of differential equations. Using the `TrekParameters` option, you can give the equation with symbolic parameters, which are controlled through the `EquationTrekker` window interface.

   [image]

Answer (score 4):

Dave Bailey maintains a package called SWP that you might find useful:

[Super Widget Package](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/superwidgetpackage/superwidgetpackage.html)