# Dial control for Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, gui-construction

I'm trying to make a control item in a `Manipulate` that is a simple dial. I'm trying to mimic `Manipulate[theta, {theta, 0, 360}]`, but with a `dial` instead of a `Slider`.

I've sort of done this (see code below), but my variable pt doesn't reset to its original value when I hit the `ResetButton`. Any help would be appreciated.

```
DynamicModule[
 {pt = {0.5, 0.5}},
 Manipulate[
  ArcTan @@ pt,
  DynamicModule[
   {},
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pt],
    Graphics[
     {
      Line[{{1.1, 0}, {0, 0}}],
      EdgeForm[Thin],
      {LightGray, Disk[]},
      {Lighter@Lighter@LightGray, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]},
      Dynamic[Disk[0.7 Normalize[pt], 0.08]]
      },
     PlotRange -> 1.3,
     ImageSize -> 60],
    Appearance -> None
    ]
   ],
  AppearanceElements -> "ResetButton"
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Would an `AngularGauge` suffice as the control? If so, that would save a lot of coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because `ResetButton` refers to `` Manipulate`s `` initial state while `pt` is outer `DynamicModule` variable here. You can scope variables in `Manipulate` with a cool trick,
which I've learned here: `{{pt, {0.5, 0.5}}, None}`

```
Manipulate[
  ArcTan @@ pt,
  {{pt, {0.5, 0.5}}, None},
  DynamicModule[{}, LocatorPane[   Dynamic[pt], 
                     Graphics[{Line[{{1.1, 0}, {0, 0}}], EdgeForm[Thin],
                           {LightGray, Disk[]}, {Lighter@Lighter@LightGray, 
                           Disk[{0, 0}, 0.9]}, Dynamic[Disk[0.7 Normalize[pt], 0.08]]}, 
                           PlotRange -> 1.3, ImageSize -> 60], Appearance -> None]], 
 AppearanceElements -> "ResetButton"]
```

> [image]

Comment: p.s. you may be interested in [AngularSlider](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5121/5478), interesting but undocumented so it's hard to use it with luck and it seem to have couple of issues. But still, worth to know.

Comment: Oh, man. That does it. Thanks.

Comment: @rhomboidRhipper I'm glad I could help. Good luck. ;)